# Getting javax.Naming.NameNotFoundException when calling WebMethod in JEE 5

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb

I'm using JEE version 5.0.2. I'm calling a WebMethod in a @WebService annotated class. This annotated class calls a Stateless @EJB that contains the business logic (the implementation) of the WebMethod I'm calling.

My WebService class is defined as follows:

```
@WebService
HandlerChain(file = "MyXService_handle.xml")
public class MyXService {

@EJB(mappedName="MyXBean", beanName="MyXBean")
public MyXBean myXBean;

@WebMethod
public String sayHello(@WebParam(name="nTimes") int nTimes) {
    return myXBean.sayHello(nTimes);
   }
}
```

My EJB is defined as follows:

```
@Stateless(name="MyXBean", mappedName="MyXBean")
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)
public class MyXBean {

@PersistenceContext name="persistence/my_PU", unitName="my_PU")
protected EntityManager entityManager;

public String sayHello(int nTimes) {
    String s = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < nTimes; i++) {
         s += "Hello";
    }
    return s;
    }
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Caused by: com.sun.enterprise.InjectionException: Exception attempting to inject Unresolved Ejb-Ref com.my.domain.MyXService/myXBean@jndi: MyXBean@null@com.my.domain.MyXBean@Session@MyXBean into class com.sun.enterprise.webservice.JAXWSServlet
    at com.sun.enterprise.util.InjectionManagerImpl._inject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:387)
    at com.sun.enterprise.util.InjectionManagerImpl.inject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:206)
    at com.sun.enterprise.util.InjectionManagerImpl.injectInstance(InjectionManagerImpl.java:117)
    at com.sun.web.server.J2EEInstanceListener.handleBeforeEvent(J2EEInstanceListener.java:259)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: MyXBean#com.my.domain.MyXBean not found
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.TransientContext.doLookup(TransientContext.java:216)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.TransientContext.lookup(TransientContext.java:188)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialContextProviderImpl.lookup(SerialContextProviderImpl.java:74)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.LocalSerialContextProviderImpl.lookup(LocalSerialContextProviderImpl.java:111)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:409)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.NamingManagerImpl.lookup(NamingManagerImpl.java:944)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.java.javaURLContext.lookup(javaURLContext.java:173)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:407)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
    at com.sun.enterprise.util.InjectionManagerImpl._inject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:287)
    ... 34 more
|#]
```

The WebService class and the EJB are exactly in the same module in the same WAR. This WAR is being deployed in a Glassfish Server version 2.1.1. I only get this warning in the deploy log (server.log):

```
[#|2018-12-10T22:51:59.045+0100|WARNING|sun-appserver2.1|javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment|_ThreadID=78;_ThreadName=Thread-946;_RequestID=bf2b9b34-5240-4eca-8b4b-9d16baad7c5b;|Unresolved <ejb-link>: MyXBean|#]
```

I'm following the Java EE 5 specification to implement all of this, so I'm trying to do my architecture "by the book".

I already tried to implement an interface as explained in here https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbmg.html but with no avail, the error persisted.

I have no xml configuration concerning the beans. I was expecting all to work via the annotations but I'm getting the javax.Naming.NameNotFoundException explained above.

Am I missing something? I'm available to give more details if needed.

Thank you.

Comment: Regarding _"I'm following the Java EE 5 specification to implement all of this"_, EE 6 was released exactly nine years ago today, and the current specification is EE 8. Is there any reason that you are using such an obsolete specification? Why not just use EE 8?

Comment: An obsolete tool being used in the project depends on Java EE 5 and would be risky to change the version for now. So I must cope with that. I still don't have a solution for the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the ejb name and the mapped name. The usage of mapped name is vendor specific. Glassfish is using this as a "global JNDI name". Since you are using both, I don't know  which one will take precedence over the other. With your example, empty @EJB and @Stateless anntoations should work.